# Double slit experiment: Plotting contributions from individual slits

Tags: interference, double-slit-experiment

I'm looking at the double slit interference experiment. I'm trying to plot the answer the question "what is the contribution of each slit to the total intensity".

The quantitative solution of the problem at position $r$, for sources $U_1$ and $U_2$ projected on a screen is:

\begin{equation}
U(r) = U_1(r) + U_2(r)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
I(r)=I_1(r)+I_2(r)+ 2 \sqrt{I_1(r) I_2(r)} \cos (\Phi(r))
\end{equation}

where $I_1=|U_{1}|^2$, $I_2=|U_{2}|^2$, and $\Phi$ is the phase difference between the two waves, at that position. When projected onto a screen, the intensity forms a sinusoidally varying intensity profile.

It's very easy to pull out the contribution of each source on the total wave amplitude, but unclear to me how you could pinpoint the "contribution" of each wave to the total intensity because of the cross term, and subsequently plot it as a function of position on the screen. Ideally, I would be able to make a stacked area chart of the contributions of the two sources.

So far, my best idea is plotting 3 components instead of 2 (individual intensities + the cross term), but there may be better methods that I'm missing.

Would you have any suggestions?